# tool tip not showing for button in custom menu item

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSPopUpButton object in modal window. 
I have set my custom view to menu item associated with the the pop up button object. 
In that custom view I have two subviews one NSTextfield object and another NSButton object.
I have set tool tip for both the objects and custom view as well.
Again. I have set tool tip for menu item as well.

To my surprise, tool tip for the the custom view and its subviews are not displayed whereas tool tip for menu item is displayed.

On other hand, if the same procedure is set in non modal window all the tool tips are displayed.

Can any one explain why the tool tips for the objects on modal window are not displayed?